# React Navigation Pass Object Between Classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm a bit stuck trying to generate a list of objects in React Native, and would appreciate the help a lot. I have a `HomeScreen.js` that displays the list, and has a button that navigates to `NewMedScreen.js`, that has two inputs and a submit button. They are in a stack navigator together, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the object I generate in `NewMedScreen` back to be read. Ideally I create the list in my root, `App.js`, to be used everywhere, but I would also be okay with creating it in `HomeScreen`

Here are all 3:

App.js, here I have the empty list of meds, and a method for potentially adding the objects passed from NewMedScreen to it. The idea was that when I generate this list in my HomeScreen, I can pull it from that source. I very much like the idea of having a single source in my app, if possible.

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator 
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="New Medication" component={newMedScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

class App extends Component{

  // Creates the initial state of meds, an empty array
  state = {
    meds: []
  }

  //Adds a new medication to the existing list of medications
  addMed = (med) => {
    const meds = this.state.meds
    meds.push(med)
    this.setState({ meds })
    console.log(meds)
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyStack/>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

HomeScreen.js  (I have not built the list yet):

```js
class HomeScreen extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
                <Heading message="meds" />
                <Text style={styles.text}>Home</Text>
            </ScrollView>
            <Button />
        </View>
    )}
}
```

And NewMed.js:

```js
class newMedScreen extends React.Component{
    
    // Set the default state
    state = {
        med: '',
        dose: ''
      }
      // onChangeText method to set the state to match the input value
      onChangeText = (key, value) => {
        this.setState({ [key]: value })
        console.log(value)
      }

    // Triggered when submit button is pressed
      submit = () => {
          // If one or both fields are empty, alert and return
        if (this.state.med === '' || this.state.dose === ''){ 
            alert('Please fill out both fields')
            return
        }
        // Create the 'med' object, setting the state equal to the input, and giving it a unique ID
        const med = {
          med: this.state.med,
          dose: this.state.dose,
          id: uuidV4(),
        }
        console.log(med)
        // Trigger the addMed method inside of App.js, that adds the med to a list of meds
        // Set the input fields back
        this.setState({
          med: '',
          dose: ''
        }, () => {
            // Go to the home screen
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', { med })
        })
      }
```

Please help me figure this out. I am very stuck, and pretty new at this.

Comment: Your best option would be to use a state management library like `redux` or `mobx`. If this is going to be a simple application with not many global states you can use the built-in `Context` api of React. [React Context Api Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) [React Context: The Easy Way (With Class Component) Blog Post](https://dev.to/evangunawan/react-context-the-easy-way-stateful-component-bh0)

Comment: The only global state I need is the list of objects. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Context api would be the best for you then